# Multidimensional data structure?

Tags: c#, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I need a multidimensional data structure with a row and a column.

- Must be able to insert elements any location in the data structure. Example: `{A , B}` I want to insert `C` in between `A` and `B`. `{A, C, B}`.
- Dynamic: I do not know the size of the data structure.
- Another example: I know the [row][col] of where I want to insert the element. EX. `insert("A", 1, 5)`, where `A` is the *element* to be inserted, `1` is the *row*, `5` is the *column*.

**EDIT**
I want to be able to insert like this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        List<List<string()>> list = new List<List<string>()>();
        list.Insert("RAWR", 1, 2); // RAWR is the element to insert, 1 is the row, 2 is the col.
        list.Insert("Hello", 3, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

And of course this does not work, because the list does not support this functionality. I understand this code is bad, but I just want to get across what I am trying to accomplish.

So in a sense I will have a user who will choose which ROW and COL to insert the element to.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? [ask]

Comment: And if you insert at [1,5], what happens. Does everything in that row shift right? Or does the insertion cause item [1,end] to move to [2,0]? That is, does it shift items in the entire grid?

Comment: I have tried using a DataTable, but DataTable's do not allow me to insert in any location of the Table, I have tried arrays but I do not know the size of the array. I have tried Lists, but Lists do not allow me to inesrt any location.

Comment: Perhaps an old fashioned Linked List?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: A Linked List would not work for my functionality because a Linked List would allow allow insertions on the head and the tail.

Comment: @AustinTruong - linked list allows to insert anywhere... Not sure why you think otherwise...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It allows it, but it's extraordinarily inefficient at it.  It's also extraordinarily inefficient at accessing anywhere other than the head/tail.  On top of all of that, it also uses up a lot more memory per item than most other data structures.

Comment: @Servy, Yes, my comment was about about only insertions head/tail, not that one should use linked list. Joking mode on: "extraordinarily inefficient at insert" as in "as inefficient as accepted answer with inserting into array" and "lot more memory per item" is basically the same overhead as dictionaries/hash tables... :) joking mode end.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's simply not true.  The big-oh value for insertion is the same for the middle of a list vs an array list, but that doesn't mean they're the same.  A list will still be *much* more efficient when looked at with finer granularity.  As for memory, Dictionaries will use up about twice the memory they really need in the worst case, and less than that most of the time, a linked list will use up twice the memory it really needs in every case.  Also keep in mind that a linked list causes a lot of memory fragmentation, thus functionally consuming more than it appears to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a list of lists should work fine:

```
IList<IList<T>> multiDim = new List<IList<T>>();
```

You can insert new rows like this:

```
multiDim.Insert(atRow, new List<T>());
```

or insert a new element in a specific row:

```
multiDim[row].Insert(atColumn, myElement);
```

Note that you need to have enough elements in your list in order to call an `Insert`; otherwise, you will get an out-of-range exception. The easiest way to address this is to write a small utility method that adds empty items until the insertion is possible:

```
private static Expand<T>(IList<T> list, int index) {
    while (list.Count < index) {
        list.Add(default(T));
    }
}
```

Rewrite your program as follows:

```
Expand(list, 1);
list.Insert(1, "HELLO");
Expand(list, 5);
list.Insert(5, "RAWR");
```

Comment: NVM, i am still having the problem. adding an edit to my post of the problem. Thank you though for the input!

Comment: hmmmm I see that is a way to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) might work with a Tuple as it's key:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string> dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>();
dict.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 5), "A");
```

Comment: You may want to use `Tuple.Create` rather than the contructor.  That's the general convention anyway.

Comment: Hmmm okay. I am trying to still understand how the Tuple works.

Comment: @AustinTruong `Tuple` is merely a simple data holder class.  In this case it would be (close to) the same as creating a class with two integer properties, although it's worth noting that it's immutable, and it also intelligently overload `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so it will work well as the key in a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

[`SortedDictionary<int, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) seem to fit perfectly if your keys are integers or anything ordered like strings. Just put items by key to the dictionary.

```
var sparseArray = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
sparseArray.Add(1, "notepad.exe");
sparseArray.Add(5, "paint.exe");
sparseArray.Add(3, "paint.exe");
sparseArray.Add(2, "wordpad.exe");
```

Comment: The key seems to be a pair of integers, not a single integer, so maybe a `Tuple<int,int>`.

Comment: Okay, so how would I do this multi-dimensional?

Comment: My edit has made it more clear was I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AustinTruong As I said, and as is demonstrated in another answer, use a `Tuple<int,int>` as the key, rather than a single int.  Also I see no reason to use a `SortedDictionary` over a regular `Dictionary`.

Comment: Okay thanks! sorry right now I am trying to understand how this Tuple works. Haha.

Comment: @Servy, I suspect more like `SortedDictionary<KeyRow, SortedDictionary<KeyColumn, T>>` as question seem to require sparse array on both Row and Column dimensions. But I hope Austin will figure out what is needed (if SortedDictionary works for the casee).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Nope, creating a dictionary of dictionaries would very likely be less efficient, and would actually be even worse if it's sparse in both dimensions.  There is overhead associated with creating a dictionary, and creating N dictionaries is therefore expensive, and results in a lot of overhead.  It would only be not terrible if the first dimension is sparse but the second is well populated (in which case the inner data structure should probably be a `List`, not a dictionary).  What problem do you forsee with using a Tuple as a key?

Comment: @Servy, Nothing wrong with `Tuple<row,col>` (I assume is what you mean), also iteration per row is more complicated that `Keys`. I doubt efficiency is of a concern based on accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, querying the two options would be different.  If you frequently want to get all items in a row it would be less efficient with one dictionary than with nested dictionaries.